# How to generate a positive skewed array?

Tags: python, data, distribution

As the title suggests, I would like to specify the task that I really need help with:

Given three possible distributions of an array:

[image]

I know that given a skewed dataset (the left and the right), then do the log transformation can approximately transform it back to the normal distribution (the middle one)
So I tried to reverse the process by applying exponential `exp` to generate the skewed one, here is my code:

```py
 #create a normal distribution(0 -> 1) array of 200 examples
mu , sigma = 0.2 , 0.1
normal_distributed = np.random.default_rng().normal(mu, sigma, 200)  

 #restore the skewed one   
skewed_distributed = np.exp(normal_distributed)

 #Try to make it more skewed
N = 2   
for i in range(N):
  skewed_distributed = np.exp(skewed_distributed)
```

and I plotted it out:

[image]     [image]

But I really would like to ask, is there any module or function that could generate a positive/negative skewed data immediately? Or do I have to do the inverse like this to get the skewed data? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [`scipy.stats.skewnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html)? This allows you to generate a skewed normal distribution, with a parameter `a` to control the skewness of the distribution.

Comment: Oh I have just checked it out. Thank you so much !!